# aframe camera switch between exit vr and enter vr

Tags: three.js, camera, virtual-reality, aframe, webvr

how is it possible to switch between the camera on desktop and VR?
i wanna use  the mouse-cursor on desktop and when i enter VR  it should switch to another camera with cursor-fusing.

here is my code:

```
<a-entity id="cam-desktop" camera="userHeight: 1.6; zoom:1 " look-controls mouse-cursor>
</a-entity>


<a-entity id="cam-vr" camera="userHeight: 1.6; zoom:1 " look-controls>
    <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" delay=" 3000" attribute="camera.zoom" from="1" to="4" dur="1000"></a-animation>
  <a-animation begin="click" delay="500" attribute="camera.zoom" from="4" to="1" dur="1000"></a-animation>
    <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout:4000" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03; thetaLength: 360; thetaStart: 0" rotation="0 0 90" position="0 0 -1" material="color: black; side: double; shader: flat">
    <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" attribute="geometry.thetaLength" from="360" to="0" easing="linear" dur="3000"></a-animation>
    <a-animation begin="mouseleave" attribute="geometry.thetaLength" from="360" to="360" dur="0"></a-animation>
    </entity>
</a-entity>
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a component, which listenes to the 'enter-vr' and 'exit-vr' events, and set the active camera accordingly:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('scenelistener',{
   init:function(){
      let vrcam = document.querySelector("#cam-vr");
      let dcam = document.querySelector("#cam-desktop");
      let  vrmode = false;
      this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('enter-vr',function(){
           if(!vrmode){
               dcam.setAttribute('active',false);
               vrcam.setAttribute('active',true);
               vrmode!=vrmode;
           }
      }
      this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('exit-vr',function(){
           if(vrmode){
               dcam.setAttribute('active',true);
               vrcam.setAttribute('active',false);
               vrmode!=vrmode;
           }
      }
  }
});
```

Actually, You can just paste the listeners anywhere, moreover You could just listen to any event and do stuff accordingly to the received event, I just wanted to show You the concept.
Im not sure what happens if 2+ camera's are active, so i made them false on change.
**UPDATE**
I did not see that the cameras are entities, not primitives, so You have to set the attribute like this: `setAttribute('camera','active',true)`
I have some issues with the cursor, so i make it visible and invisible, depending on the vr state.
Working fiddle ( at least the camera switch ) [here](https://jsfiddle.net/phjjn6p3/).

Comment: i dont get it, it doesnt work :-/
why is the vr-cam and desktop-cam false and true at the same time?
#cam-vr should be active in vr and not active in non-vr. and #cam-desktop active in non-vr and not active in vr.

the camera souldnt be active at the same time. :-(

Comment: i did it like this so that they are not active at the same time, in the next line i set the proper one active, i can swap it to a simple check

Comment: thanks for your help, but the cursor moved to the ground under the camera. and switch doesnt work or im to stupid for that. check it out here: http://www.davidklapheck.de/webvr/navbar.html

i think i have to try another solution.

Comment: Thank you very very much. it works! :-D
you are the best.

if have asked the question here before, but do you have an idea why the zoom animation in vr-mode isnt working?

Comment: @Stephan glad i could help, I managed to reproduce the issue with the zoom, but i have no idea why it doesn't work as expected.